# Sync two owncloud servers using windows client

Tags: owncloud

I'm using Owncloud on personal server for personal data, and need to connect to business-related server for business data. Server-to-server sharing is unappealing because of wasting costly hosted storage (and some other arguments). Is there a way to make windows client sync both servers simultaneously?

Comment: I don't think this is facilitated at the moment. But this would be a great addition for the owncloud. Did you try the mailing list of owncloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a feature currently doesn't exist. Two possible "workarounds" are listened here:

https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=20521

An implementation of this feature without workarounds are planned for 1.9:

https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/43